# Jsch SFTP client unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sftp, jsch

I use Jsch as SFTP client to read and write XML files from a remote SFTP directory.

I use a 5 second job to check if new files available for drafts, after 30 or 40 min loop I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:528) [jsch-0.1.53.jar:]
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183) [jsch-0.1.53.jar:]
```

This is the source code used to create connexion

```
 public InputStream getFile(String path){
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    try {

      ChannelSftp sftp = openConnexion(session, channel);
      return sftp.get(path);

    } catch (SftpException e) {
      new RuntimeException("Error detected during get file from SFTP specific path : " + e.getMessage(), e);

    } finally {
      closeConnexion(session, channel);
    }
 }

 private ChannelSftp openConnexion(Session session, Channel channel) {
    try {
      JSch ssh = new JSch();
      session = ssh.getSession("user", "hostname", 22);
      session.setPassword("password");
      session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
      session.connect();
      channel = session.openChannel(SFTP_CHANNEL);
      channel.connect();
      ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

      return sftp;

    } catch (JSchException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error detected during open SFTP connexion : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }

  private void closeConnexion(Session session, Channel channel) {
    if (channel != null) {
      channel.disconnect();
    }
    if (session != null) {
      session.disconnect();
    }
  }
```

I tried to increase the size of JVM thread stack and also increase the limits of native process allowed by unix => same error.

I used the following command to do that :

```
ulimit -u unlimited
```

I tried to create a pool of jsch session, jsch session when it is not disconnected, it is unusable => "SFTP Error 4"

My job is runned into war deployed on jboss-as-7, this is the JVM option :

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xss1024k"
```

Do you have a suggestion for this kind of treatment?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you close the connection after searching?

Comment: Post the code. Also how much JVM memory are you allocating on startup?

Comment: Source code added. JVM option agrs also.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: A quick glance at the code indicates that you're creating a fresh `Session` and `Channel` object per fetch, and unless there's some code assigning the session and channel to the variables `session` and `channel` from the object context, you're never freeing them up.

Comment: Thank you Petesh for your answer. My source code is updated to see you how i create new channel and session for each instance of loop...can you explain me how freeing session and channel after each use ? for me invoke disconnect() method is enough

Comment: There's a problem here in that you can't safely close the connection in the try-finally block because you'll end up closing the input stream that you're trying to read from. In addition, you can't assign to the variable that you're passing into the `openConnexion` call as it will be lost once the routine goes out of scope. I'll try to construct a slightly better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not closing the channel and session after each loop, which will leak at least the thread that's used to perform the download over SFTP.

The attempt to close the session and channel in the finally block, if it worked, would unfortunately invalidate the InputStream that you're trying to read from; preventing you from processing the file properly.

I'm going to refactor the code slightly, which should address the resource exhaustion issue, with comments:

```
// session and channel are at the object scope
Session session = null;
Channel channel = null;

public InputStream getFile(String path){
    // First, close any existing connections.
    try {
      closeConnexion();
    } catch (SftpException e) {
      // You can try to handle an issue here; but it's
      // probably not worth it
    }
    try {
      ChannelSftp sftp = openConnexion();
      return sftp.get(path);
    } catch (SftpException e) {
      new RuntimeException("Error detected during get file from SFTP specific path : " + e.getMessage(), e);

    } finally {
    }
 }

 private ChannelSftp openConnexion() {
    try {
      JSch ssh = new JSch();
      // use the object's session variable
      session = ssh.getSession("user", "hostname", 22);
      session.setPassword("password");
      session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
      session.connect();
      // use the object's channel object
      channel = session.openChannel(SFTP_CHANNEL);
      channel.connect();
      ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

      return sftp;

    } catch (JSchException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error detected during open SFTP connexion : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }

  private void closeConnexion() {
    // close object's channel and session
    if (channel != null) {
      channel.disconnect();
      channel = null;
    }
    if (session != null) {
      session.disconnect();
      session = null;
    }
  }
```

If I was to re-design this, I would return a container class rather than an InputStream that contained the channel, session and InputStream. The container class would have a 'close' method, which would close the InputStream, channel and session, and then I wouldn't store the channel and session in the object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! you are right, apparently inputstream remains open...i will test your proposal.